# Cross-object email formula fields

Tags: workflow, formula-field, email-alert

I cannot use the email field from a grand parent object as a recipient in my workflow that is triggered from the child object. I am getting stuck because the formula field I use to populate the email address on the child object is not an eligible recipient since it's a formula field and not an email field. Also, there is no email option when creating this formula field as the return type. This is a big showstopper when trying to automate several of our workflow processes.

Any workaround other than creating Email field on child and populating it using workflow field update

Comment: Process Builder would be an alternative without going all the way to triggers. It's going to be that sort of approach, though, I would think. That's the only way you're going to make it an email field. PB might be better than WF because you can propagate the changes down from the grandparent as well.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I need Grandparent email id as recepient of my email alert which is not possible even with process builder

Comment: He meant using PB to populate an email field on the grandchild object, I think. You won't be able to send an email alert without an Email type field on the object itself.